# How to return to the last used activity from another package. Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, package, flags

I have an application with 4 packages. I can start one of those packages with the actionbar. Inside all the packages is an alarmManager. The alarmManager start an Activity in his own package.  Lets say the Activity state is in the 3th activity from the first package. And the alarmManager of the second package is working, and opend the 4th Acitivy from (his) the second package. **Now my question is how do I go back to my last used activity in the *first* package?** I want this with an menu item in the action bar, and also an item to switch back to my last activity in the second package.  Without using the back button.

I have looked and tryed for hours, with intent flags, but can't find the right one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the current activity, say you are in the **activityThree** of the **package 3** and you want to go back to the activityFirst of the first package. In the activityThree you have to add this code to the click Listener to go to **"activityFirst"** activity.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), activityFirst.class);
StartActivity(i);
```

and in the manifest.xml you have  to add these lines

```
<activity android:name="com.example.package1.activityFirst"
    android:label="First Activity">

   </activity>
```

And One thing more you have to import the package1 (Package name of **activityFirst** ) name in the **activityThree** code like this `import com.example.package1.activityFirst;`
and inthe same way you can go back by adding this lines in activity **activityFirst**.

Comment: No this was not my question. If the app is somewhere in the first package, and the AlarmMananger takes over and opends a Activity in the 3th package. How do you go back to your last Activity? in the first package?